# Jquery Full Calendar Remove Scroll Bar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I Have the jquery full calendar in use, but im trying to get rid of the scroll bar.
Ive tried setting the height, does not work.

Anyone have a fix (that they have used!, no links- I've tried most of them)?

I'm using:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        firstDay: 1,
        minTime:@Model.MinHour,
       maxTime:@Model.MaxHour})
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Page is big enough, just cant get the darn thing to go!

Answer (score 22):

Try this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight
    contentHeight:"auto", is used for remove scroll bar

```
<script>

        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        showNonCurrentDates:false,
        fixedWeekCount:false,
        contentHeight:"auto",
        handleWindowResize:true,
        themeSystem:'bootstrap3',

    });
</script>
```

Comment: contentHeight:"auto", try this for remove scroll bar

Comment: This would be the ideal way of doing it, thanks

Answer (score 13):

I set height and contentHeight to the same value and it seems to have done the trick.

css:

```
#calendar {
   height:1000px;
}
```

js:

```
var calHeight = 1000;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height:calHeight,
    contentHeight:calHeight
});
```

**Edit:**

I found on refresh between views, caused it to show scroll when I don't want it to. 
Added this:

```
.fc-scroller {
   overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of version 2.1.0 height option can be set to 'auto'

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/

This will remove the vertical scrollbar

Answer (score 5):

Although its documentation says that `auto` option given for [height](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/height) and [contentHeight](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/contentHeight) works but only for versions above `2.1.0`.

This code worked for me for any version:

```
.fc-scroller {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Crete a div containing your calendar and then put in the css `overflow-y:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;`

```
div class="container-calendar"

.container-calendar {

overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `height: 'auto'` to remove scrolls

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height:'auto',
    ...
 });
```

Comment: with the newer versions of fullcalendar, this is the ideal answer

Answer (score 1):

In fullcalendar version 2.7.1 this can be fixed commenting the lines with the call to the function that sets the overflows:

```
this.applyOverflow();
```

There are 2 functions calling this function: clear (around line 8855) and render (around line 8843)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
                aspectRatio: 1.605,  -> this works for me
```

Comment: This answer might be correct, but it would help if you explained why it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try expanding the width of the calender to make the scrollbar out of the right side of the viewport, and then set overflow-x: hidden for the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        height: 300,
        contentHeight: 360,
    });
});
```

These 300 and 360 are an example, You can set them to whatever you'd like while the idea remains the same ..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the a later version which solved the bug

Answer (score -2):

You could try 2 things:

CSS: Wrap Calendar in div

```
div id{
overflow:hidden
}
```

JS:

```
$('#calendar').height($(window).height());
```

Should fix you issue.

Comment: Quesiton how would you add the scroll bar when it is on either the tablet or phone version?